# j2me wireless connection

Tags: wifi, java-me

I'm using ME Platform SDK 3.0. I'm new in this program. I am trying to create a java application that can return on my "DeflaulCldcPhone" all the wireless network connections available. Can someone tell me how to do that? Also can someone please tell me how to connect to a wireless network after detecting it? (I'm working in Windows XP)

Comment: I cannot understand ur question.So please mentioned elaborately and as well as some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

J2ME dosn't know anything about the underlying physical network. There are some attempts to provide an API in the JSR 309. However, you won't find a lot of devices out there which are supporting it.

Have you thought of writing a native app, e.g. for the S60 platform? Good luck.